# Getting the bounding box of a currency note in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, bounding-box

I want to crop the bounding box of a currency note. I have the following code which draws the bounding boxes for the contours in the image. With the drawn rectangles, I want to crop the largest rectangle. Could somebody point me how I could do that.

The code I have is as follows.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 100;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);

/// Function header
void thresh_callback(int, void* );

/**
 * @function main
 */
int main( int, char** argv )
{
  /// Load source image and convert it to gray
  src = imread( "image_of_the_currency_note.jpg", 1 );

  /// Convert image to gray and blur it
  cvtColor( src, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
  blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3) );

  /// Create Window
  const char* source_window = "Source";
  namedWindow( source_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( source_window, src );

  createTrackbar( " Threshold:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );
  thresh_callback( 0, 0 );

  waitKey(0);
  return(0);
}

/**
 * @function thresh_callback
 */
void thresh_callback(int, void* )
{
  Mat threshold_output;
  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

  /// Detect edges using Threshold
  threshold( src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY );
  /// Find contours
  findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

  /// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects
  vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
  vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
  //vector<Point2f>center( contours.size() );
  //vector<float>radius( contours.size() );

  for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
     { approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
       boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
     }


  /// Draw polygonal contour + bonding rects
  Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
  for( size_t i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
     {
       Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
       drawContours( drawing, contours_poly, (int)i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
       rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
     }

  /// Show in a window
  namedWindow( "Contours", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Contours", drawing );
}
```

The images are attached here. "image_of_the_currency_note" is the original image and "bounding_box_drawn_for_the_contours_in_the_currency_note" shows the bounding boxes drawn for the original image. I want to get the largest bounding box in the image to a opencv Mat object.

http://oi57.tinypic.com/wjcade.jpg - image_of_the_currency_note

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2cqzbsh.jpg - bounding_box_drawn_for_the_contours_in_the_currency_note

If somebody could show me how to do that it would be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check that `boundRect[i].width > threshold  && boundRect[i].height > threshold`. The threshold could be one-third of image size. So, if the `boundRect[i]` passes the condition then keep it else discard it. In this way, you would be able to get the largest rectangle.

**Another Method**

Your each contour consists of four points(e.g. A,B,C,D) of the rectangle. You just have to extract the  x and y coordinates values of each point of a contour.

After extracting the x and y values of each point, you just need to set a condition that if ( distance between two subsequent points > certain value ) then keep that contour otherwise discard it.

**For example:** just check whether ( B.x - A.x  >  100) then if true..keep the contour.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will check this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I found the contourArea() function in opencv and decided to use that to get the largest contour and drew the bounding box of that largest contour.

```
  int largest_area=0;
  int largest_contour_index=0;
  Rect bounding_rect;

  for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) { 
      double a=contourArea( contours[i],false);  //  Find the area of contour
      if(a>largest_area){
        largest_area=a;
        largest_contour_index=i;                //Store the index of largest contour
        bounding_rect=boundingRect(contours[i]); // Find the bounding rectangle for biggest contour
      }

  }

  Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
  //drawContours( src, contours,largest_contour_index, color, CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy ); // Draw the largest contour using previously stored index.
  rectangle(src, bounding_rect,  Scalar(0,255,0),1, 8,0);
```